# JetPack Compose for library development

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-library

We are about to start greenfield development of an **Android library** and considering using JetPack Compose for UI elements used there.
I know that one restriction to consider is API 21+ (not really a problem).
Are there any other reasons to use or not use Jetpack Compose for **library** development?

Comment: Did you end up using it? Were there any other restrictions? In terms of compose compiler/kotlin version or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not sure if that's a definite "no" for usage (that's rather subjective), but you have to bring the dependency on the compose along with the library. This will affect the library and app size